# How to use Excel macro to add text to file name

Tags: excel, vba

I recorded a macro in excel to make some formatting changes to spreadsheets. I’m planning to run it every time I open a new export to begin working with it. I’d also like my macro to rename the file, based on the original name but adding more words.

For example:

Old file name: Sales.xls

New file name: 2019.07.10 Export Sales Backup.xlsx

The original file name will be different every time (“Sales”, “Mailing”, etc.), so I need the code to be based on the old name and not just dub everything Sales. The folder will always be the same—the file will always come from Desktop and get saved to Desktop.

I’ve read some questions about renaming but I can’t figure out how to parse the original file name to separate out the file path and only keep the bit I need. I’ve also seen questions that are about a batch rename, but I want to do this as part of an existing excel macro that I’ll already be running anyway. I’ve already read through these forums and figured out how to add the date and change the file format.

My current code says:

```
Sub Test()

FName = "C:\Users\Grace\Desktop\" & Format(Date, "yyyy.mm.dd") & ".xlsx"
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=FName, _
    FileFormat:= _
        xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False

End Sub
```

I don't know where to start with trying to keep the original file name. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can get the name of the currently opened file with `ActiveWorkbook.Name`

Comment: @GraceBrazen, were you able to figure it?

Comment: Thank you! @cybernetic.nomad That kind of worked, but since it includes the file extension, and since I'm appending words at the end, I end up with file names like:

"2019.07.10 octopus.xlsx – BACKUP.xlsx"

Is there a way to remove the file extension from the name?

Comment: You can remove the extension by [manipulating the string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/functions/string-functions). Replacing `".xlsx"` with `"-- BACKUP.xlsx"` should work

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad thanks for the link! It's a bit advanced for me so I'll bookmark it to study later. In the meantime I found a thread on here that recommended using Left(Filename, Len(Filename) - 4), so I did that but replaced it with ActiveWorkbook.Name per your suggestion, and that did the trick. Thanks so much for your help! I'm really grateful it was such a simple fix.